# ps1 not giving result in dos shell

Tags: powershell

My script....

```
function DirSize {
    BEGIN {}
         PROCESS
    {
        $timer = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
        $bFile="C:\00mpd\DR\mrv_incr_"+$timer+".txt"
        $data = Get-Content "C:\00mpd\DR\vaults.txt"
        write-host $data.count total lines read from file
        foreach ($line in $data)
        {
            write-host $line
            $a=0
            foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $line -recurse -Force| where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddHours(-1))} ))
            {
                $a+=$file.length/1GB
            }
            Write-Output "$line :: $a GB"
            "$line :: $a GB"| Out-File $bFile -append
        }
    }   
    END {}
} # end function Get-DirSize
```

vaults.txt contents name of the various folders....

```
d:\Milind_laptop_backup\DDrive\Milind_pst\
d:\Milind_laptop_backup\DDrive\Office\
d:\Milind_laptop_backup\DDrive\personal\
d:\Milind_laptop_backup\DDrive\ToMilind\
```

Above ps1 give proper result when running in powershell window. But when I'm running same in dos shell, it's not giving any result.

Powershell commands

```
PS C:\> . "c:\00mpd\dr\dirsize.ps1"
PS C:\> DirSize
```

But when I tried in Dos shell, no result is coming out.

```
C:\00mpd\DR>powershell -File "c:\00mpd\dr\DirSize.ps1"
```

Comment: `powershell -Command ". c:\00mpd\dr\DirSize.ps1; DirSize"`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the prompt response....

Answer (score 2):

You are running the script as function

This is OK when you are executing it from Inside PowerShell, The `Function DirSize` Load it and `DirSize` to Execute it. but when run it from .ps1 file it just loads the function but not executing it.

To Solve this:

**Method 1:**

Remove the `function DirSize {` and the last line `} # end function Get-DirSize`

**Method 2:**

Dot Source the .ps1 as a command to load the function then run it after

```
powershell -Command ". c:\00mpd\dr\DirSize.ps1; DirSize"
```

As Mathias R. Jessen Suggested

Answer (score -1):

As others have said if you remove

```
function DirSize{ }
```

and dot source your script, it will solve one issue.

I would personally then change Write-Output to Write-Host. It should give the result that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This will be useful for future.